# Is there a method (or tool) to convert video from a SWF container to another more portable format (e.g., H.264)

Tags: file-formats, video

I have a client who has misplaced the original source video, only has an SWF, and would like to use it in a non-flash environment.

Is there any way to do this?

So far, I've tried `ffmpeg` but it's failed, complaining about the compressed SWF.

`[swf @ 0x101807c00] Compressed SWF format not supported`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question seems more broadcast and compression specific than AV Production! Inviting experts to a new site proposal [Broadcast and Media Technologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36807/broadcast-and-media-technologies) which aims to capture more architectural and theoretical views around subjects like this. Join and invite others.

Answer (score 3):

You should get a SWF decompiler (perhaps one of the trails for: [Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/)   or [Decompiler SWF](http://www.decompiler-swf.com/)) and use that to find the nested movie file, and extract that.

Comment: Sadly, I think this is the only way out of my situation. Will confirm and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If your lucky, [VLC might be](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) able to play it. Then you can use its Convert/Save functionality to get it into a usable format.

Comment: No dice… `avformat error: av_open_input_stream failed`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a **Mac**, there's an app called [Adapter](http://www.macroplant.com/adapter/) that is supposed to [handle SWFs](http://nofilmschool.com/2011/07/adapter-favorite-audio-video-image-converter/).

If you're on **Windows**, you might try [Free SWF Convertor](http://www.freeswfconverter.com/).

Comment: Also tried Adapter with no luck. I suspect that it's choking on my “compressed” SWF

Answer (score 0):

swfextract from SWF Tools looks like it does what you want: http://wiki.swftools.org/index.php/Swfextract

It'll probably give you an FLV, but you can then use ffmpeg or similar to turn it into a better container format.

Comment: Of course having said that without trying it, I'm now struggling to get it to do that. Looks like you could build something to do this on top of it but it doesn't do it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Sony Vegas can read *some* SWF files and then you can render to any of its supported formats, including H.264. The free trial is at http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/download/trials/vegaspro